# How do you include ionic 1.2.4 in a Meteor 1.3 app?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I've tried "npm install ionic" and then  import ionic from 'ionic' does not make it available for dependency injection.  I've also tried 'meteor add driftyco:ionic' but it causes errors and complains angular to be loaded twice (I guess it conflicts with angular installed by "npm install angular" as per the 1.3 docs.)

Comment: Better to ask this question on [Meteor forums](http://forums.meteor.com) I'd say.

Comment: A similar question was posted by someone else there >1 week ago and has not been answered. https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-use-ionic-with-meteor-1-3/20540

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the meteor tutorial has been updated to include the answer: 
http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/ionic